# Uncaught TypeError in Chrome Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I am trying to make a code to draw vertical lines.

http://codepen.io/juyoung518/pen/BzAJwg

Chrome error pops up on this paragraph.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

```
function getNearestIntersections(line, arr) {
    var index = arr.length - 2;
    if (arr[index].x !== line.center.x) {
        while (Math.sign(line.center.x - line.a.x) === Math.sign(line.center.x - arr[index].x)) {
            index--;
        }
    } else {
        while (Math.sign(line.center.y - line.a.y) === Math.sign(line.center.y - arr[index].y)) {
            index--;
        }
    }

    return [arr[arr.length - 1], arr[index]];
}
```

Please can anyone tell my what the problem is?

This codepen doesn't work at all in IE.

Comment: so the index is <0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you define "line" properly? Looking at your reference I see:

```
var Line = function(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    this.a = new Vec(x1, y1);
    this.b = new Vec(x2, y2);
    this.center = new Vec((x1 + x2) / 2, (y1 + y2) / 2);
    this.dx = x2 - x1;
    this.dy = y2 - y1;
};
```

You do have this (or something similar) somewhere in your code, don't you?

Comment: I just noticed -- the same error pops up on the site referenced.